# User without the "create tags" privilege is able to create tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, privileges

On Meta Stack Overflow a user was able to create several new tags despite the fact that he doesn't have enough reputation for the "create tags" privilege ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/284350/1)). The limit is 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow.

I tried on other sites where I don't have enough rep and wasn't able to create new tags. But this user obviously was able to do that.

Comment: Perhaps the reputation limit for tag creation is incorrectly set to 300 (as for most graduated sites) on MSO, though it is listed to be at 1500.

Answer (score 6):

The rep limit was set to 300 (the default) on MSO.

I've now set it to 1500, to match Stack Overflow.

There were a few other sites that has a similar discrepancy, so I sorted them as well.

Comment: Is it intentional that the privileges page for metas redirects to the main site? I assumed the privilege to be identical due to that.

Comment: @MadScientist - yes, it is supposed to be (given that the reputation and therefore privileges are inherited from the parent site). That privileges _can_ differ is an implementation issue.

Comment: Ah, I [came across this before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261233/how-did-this-unedited-question-get-3-brand-new-tags/261234#261234)...